# unloading downloaded font issue in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, fonts, download

I'm trying to user a font provided by a server.
As this font is sometimes updated, I need to be able to load a font, unload it, and load a new version of it.

In iOS 6 all works fine, but in iOS 7, something goes wrong with the "unloading font" part of the following code.

```
    NSString* path = @"the path to my font file";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);
    CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
    NSString * newFontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    CFErrorRef registeringError = nil;

    NSLog(@"Before registering : %@",[UIFont fontWithName:newFontName size:10]);
    bool registeringSuccess = CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &registeringError);

    NSLog(@"Before unregistering : %@",[UIFont fontWithName:newFontName size:10]);

    CFErrorRef deletionError = nil;
    bool unregisteringSuccess = CTFontManagerUnregisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &deletionError);
    CGFontRelease(fontRef);
    NSLog(@"After unregistering : %@",[UIFont fontWithName:newFontName size:10]);
```

The printed log :
Before creation : (null) (this is ok)
Before deletion :  font-family: "my_font_name"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 10.00pt (this is ok)
After deletion :  font-family: "my_font_name"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 10.00pt (this is not ok, the font is still accessible by the "UIFont fontWithName" method.

both registeringSuccess and unregisteringSuccess are true
both registeringError and deletionError are nil